# Dataframe: Fetching count of records present in table A but not in table B. table B has 29 million records. (pyspark)

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

- Table A -- is a DataFrame with only 1 column and 47000 records when
  distinct applied 14000 records.
- Table B -- is a DataFrame with only 1 column and 29 million records all distinct values.

I need to get the count of records present in table A but not in Table B. but somehow i encounter below error while running below query in PySpark shell (local mode).

```
Table_A         Table_B
123450          
123451
123452          123452
123453          123453
123454          123454
                123455
                123456
                123457
```

output expected:-
2

```
DB_accnum=spark.sql("select org_acctnum from Table_A where 'some filter conditions'")

ACC_repository=spark.sql("select account_num from Table_B")

DB_accnum_d=DB_accnum.select('org_acctnum').distinct()
DB_accnum_d.persist()
broadcast(DB_accnum_d)
DB_accnum_d.count()

R_join= ACC_repository.join(DB_accnum_d,ACC_repository.account_num == 
DB_accnum.org_acctnum,how='rightouter')
R_join.count()
```

after this i get below error:-

```
R_join.count()
20/06/14 22:03:15 WARN TaskMemoryManager: Failed to allocate a page (1073741824 bytes), try again.
20/06/14 22:03:16 WARN TaskMemoryManager: Failed to allocate a page (1073741824 bytes), try again.
```

- inner join works fine.(tried count(),show (n=5) on df of inner join)
- after getting join count i intended to filter records not present in
  Table B, and then fetching count of new_DF,but got error in between.

Can anyone tell if this is the right approach or where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you already run without broadcast the table DB_accnum_d?

Comment: yes i had run without broadcast, was getting same error.  @Kafels

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running minus query or in dataframe API use exceptAll

Just make sure the column alias is same and both dataframe consists of same schema.

```py
DB_accnum = spark.sql("select org_acctnum from Table_A where 'some filter conditions'")

ACC_repository = spark.sql("select account_num as Id from Table_B")

DB_accnum_d = DB_accnum.select(col('org_acctnum').alias('Id').distinct()

difference = DB_accnum_d.exceptAll(ACC_repository)

#difference will contain the account number present in DB_accnum_d and not present in ACC_repository
difference.count()
difference.show()
```

Comment: What is your spark version

Comment: `difference=DB_accnum_d.exceptAll(ACC_repository)`
Tried it.

`Got error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'exceptAll' "`

then tried 
`difference=DB_accnum_d.subtract(ACC_repository)`

it got compiled but 
when i ran count()
`difference.count()`

`got the same error " WARN TaskMemoryManager: Failed to allocate a page (1073741824 bytes), try again." ` @shubham

spark version is -- version 2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292

Comment: Spark version --  2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292

Comment: exceptAll is exclusive to 2.4..I will remove my answer

Comment: What is your cluster size? Also you are just receiving a warning keep it running and see if you get your results

Comment: my bad..
i didn't specified it earlier - **i was running it in pyspark shell**

`now i tried it with local mode and cluster mode too.`

`it got succeeded in cluster mode while failed in client mode.`

client mode command == **spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client  /absolute_path/test.py**

cluster mode == **spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 10g --num-executors 20 --executor-memory 10g --executor-cores 15 /absolute_path/test.py**

any idea why its failing in shell mode and client mode @shubham